# saving and reloading a form with cookies using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cookies

Hello I am very new to this so I am sure my code is not optimal in any way. I am trying to save data that was inputted into a form then reload and fill out the form with the use of a cookie. When viewing the cookies in my browser I can see that the data is being saved to the cookie but it is not loading properly. I think the issue begins with the  I do not think I am properly saving or grabbing this information and I would then assume I made similar mistakes on the other select and radio button inputs. Could anyone please point me in the right direction.

****HTML:****

```
<html>
<head>
    <link id="theme" href="webdefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="pics/snow.ico">
    <title>Registration</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Week 2, conference, web, site" />
    <meta name="description" content="Conference Web Site 9 pages" />
    <meta name="author" content="Kyle Kawasaki">        
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
</head>
<body onload="loadCookies(); loadRegistration()">

        <nav id="nav"><b>
            <a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a>
            <a href="awards.html" title="Awards">Awards</a>
            <a href="activities.html" title="Activities">Activities</a> 
            <a href="meals.html" title="Meals">Meals</a>
            <a href="keynote.html" title="Keynote">Keynote</a>
            <a href="workshopschedule.html" title="WorkShopSchedule">Schedule</a>
            <a href="registration.html" title="Registration">Registration</a></b>
            <button id="black" onclick="changetheme('webdefault.css')">Black Theme</button>
            <button id="green" onclick="changetheme('style2.css')">Green Theme</button>
        </nav>

        <h1 id="h1">Conference Registration</h1><br><br><br><br>

    <div class="reg">
        <form action="thankyou.html" method="get" name="registrationForm">
            <label for="Title">Title</label>
            <select id="title">
                <optgroup label="Title">
                    <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>   
                    <option value="Mr.">Ms.</option> 
                    <option value="Mr.">Mrs.</option>  
                </optgroup>
            </select>

            <span>
            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" placeholder="John" required></span>
            <div class="hover">Who are you</div>

            <span>
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" pattern="[a-zA-Z\-]+" placeholder="Doe" required></span>
            <div class="hover">I see</div>

            <span>
            <label for="address1">Address line 1</label>
            <input type="text" id="add1" name="address1" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\ \#]+" placeholder="123 bla bla" required></span>
            <div class="hover">Tell me NOW</div>

            <span>
            <label for="address2">Address line 2</label>
            <input type="text" id="add2" name="address2" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\ \#]+" placeholder="bla bla bla"></span>
            <div class="hover">Are you done?</div>

            <span>
            <label for="City">City</label>
            <input type="text" id="city" name="city" pattern="[a-zA-Z\ ]+" placeholder="City" required></span>
            <div class="hover">Where!!</div>

            <label for="State" id = "state">State</label>
            <select name="state">
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="CA">California</option>
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select>

            <span>
            <label for="Zip">Zip Code</label>
            <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" pattern="[0-9]{5}\-[0-9]{4}" placeholder="12345-4545" required></span>
            <div class="hover">Give me what I want!!!</div>

            <span>
            <label for="tele">Telephone</label>
            <input type="text" id="tele" name="tele" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" placeholder="303-555-5555" required></span>
            <div class="hover">You can do it</div>

            <span>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="jon@doe.com" pattern="([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})" required></span>
            <div class="hover">this better be an email</div>

            <span>
            <label for="web">Company Website</label>
            <input type="text" id="web" name="web" placeholder="company.com"></span>
            <div class="hover">Rawr</div>

            <span>
            <label for="Position">Position</label>
            <input type="text" id="position" name="position" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\ \#]+" placeholder="position at company" required></span>
            <div class="hover">I bet mine is better</div>

            <span>
            <label for="Company">Company</label>
            <input type="text" id="company" name="company" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\ \#]+" placeholder="Company name" required></span>
            <div class="hover">Sweet name</div>

            <label for="Meal" id="meal">Do you want to purchase the meal pack?<br>
                Do you want to purchase just the Day 2 Dinner?</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="meal" value="Full meal pack">Full meal Pack<br>
            <input type="radio" name="meal" value="Day 2 Dinner">Day 2 Dinner<br>
            <input type="radio" name="meal" value="None">None<br><br>

            <span>
            <label for="bfname">Billing First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="bfname" name="billfirstname" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" placeholder="John" required></span>
            <div class="hover">Do it again</div>

            <span>
            <label for="blname">Billing Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="blname" name="billlastname" pattern="[a-zA-Z\-]+" placeholder="Doe" required></span>
            <div class="hover">Goon</div>

            <label for="card" id="cardtype">Choose Card type:</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="card" value="Visa">Visa<br>
            <input type="radio" name="card" value="MasterCard">MasterCard<br>
            <input type="radio" name="card" value="AmericanEx">American Express<br><br>

            <span>
            <label for="cardnum">Card Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="cardnum" name="cardnumber" pattern="[0-9]{16}" placeholder="0000000000000000" required></span>
            <div class="hover">You are mine now</div>

            <span>
            <label for="CSV">CSV</label>
            <input type="text" id="csv" name="csv" pattern="[0-9]{4}" placeholder="0000" required></span>
            <div class="hover">Almost got it</div>

            <span>
            <label for="expmo">Expiration month</label>
            <input type="text" id="expmo" name="expmonth" pattern="[0-9]{2}" placeholder="00" required></span>
            <div class="hover">Sucka</div>

            <span>
            <label for="expyr">Expiration year</label>
            <input type="text" id="expyr" name="expyr" pattern="[0-9]{4}" placeholder="0000" required></span>
            <div class="hover">Wait I need this 2</div>

            <span id="ws1">
            <input type="radio" name="wss1" value="y" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Ski<br>
            <input type="radio" name="wss1" value="n" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Snowboard<br>
            <input type="radio" name="wss1" value="y" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Walk<br>
            <br></span>

            <span id="ws2">
            <input class ="hideme" type="radio" name="wss2" id="continue1" value="y" onclick="toggle2(this)" style="visibility: hidden" />Further<br>
            <input class ="hideme" type="radio" name="wss2" id="continue2" value="y" onclick="toggle2(this)" style="visibility: hidden"/>Deeper<br>
            <input class ="hideme" type="radio" name="wss2" id="continue3" value="n" onclick="toggle2(this)" style="visibility: hidden"/>Higher<br>
            <br></span>

            <span id="ws3">
            <input type="radio" name="wss3" id="continue4" value="Continue" style="visibility: hidden" />Further<br>
            <input type="radio" name="wss3" id="continue5" value="Continue" style="visibility: hidden"/>Deeper<br>
            <input type="radio" name="wss3" id="continue6" value="Continue" style="visibility: hidden"/>Higher<br>
            <br></span>

            <script src="workshopLogic.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="saveRegistration()">
                <p class="submit">Click to finalize registration</p>
        </form>

    </div>
        <script src="saveRestoreForm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="stylesheet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

****Javascript****

```
        var conferenceId = 12345;
        var title;
        var firstName;
        var lastName;
        var address1;
        var address2;
        var City;
        var State;
        var zipCode;
        var phoneNum;
        var Email;
        var cWeb;
        var cPosition;
        var youCompany;
        var mealPlan;
        var billFirstName;
        var billLastName;
        var creditType;
        var cNum;
        var cCSV;
        var cEXPMo;
        var cEXPYr;
        var work1;
        var work2;
        var work3;

    function saveRegistration(){
        title = document.forms["registrationForm"]["firstname"].value;
        firstName = document.forms["registrationForm"]["firstname"].value;
        lastName = document.forms["registrationForm"]["lastname"].value;
        address1 = document.forms["registrationForm"]["address1"].value;
        address2 = document.forms["registrationForm"]["address2"].value;
        City = document.forms["registrationForm"]["city"].value;
        State = document.forms["registrationForm"]["state"].value;
        zipCode = document.forms["registrationForm"]["zip"].value;
        phoneNum = document.forms["registrationForm"]["tele"].value;
        Email = document.forms["registrationForm"]["email"].value;
        cWeb = document.forms["registrationForm"]["web"].value;
        cPosition = document.forms["registrationForm"]["position"].value;
        youCompany = document.forms["registrationForm"]["company"].value;
        mealPlan = document.forms["registrationForm"]["meal"].value;
        billFirstName = document.forms["registrationForm"]["billfirstname"].value;
        billLastName = document.forms["registrationForm"]["billlastname"].value;
        creditType = document.forms["registrationForm"]["card"].value;
        cNum = document.forms["registrationForm"]["cardnumber"].value;
        cCSV = document.forms["registrationForm"]["csv"].value;
        cEXPMo = document.forms["registrationForm"]["expmonth"].value;
        cEXPYr = document.forms["registrationForm"]["expyr"].value;
        work1 = document.forms["registrationForm"]["wss1"].value;
        work2 = document.forms["registrationForm"]["wss2"].value;
        work3 = document.forms["registrationForm"]["wss3"].value;

        var registrationString = title + "~" +  firstName + "~"  + lastName + "~"  + address1
                + "~"  + address2 + "~"  + City + "~"  + State + "~" + zipCode + "~"  +
                phoneNum + "~"  + Email + "~"  + cWeb + "~"  + cPosition + "~"  + youCompany
                + "~"  + mealPlan + "~"  + billFirstName + "~"  + billLastName + "~"  + 
                creditType + "~"  + cNum + "~"  + cCSV + "~"  + cEXPMo + "~"  + cEXPYr +
                "~"  + work1 + "~"  + work2 + "~"  + work3 + "~";

        setCookie(conferenceId, registrationString, 1);
    }

    function loadRegistration(){
        x = getCookie(conferenceId);

        if(x === 'error'){
            return;
        }
        else{        
            x.split("~");
            title = x[0];
            firstName = x[1];
            lastName = x[2];
            address1 = x[3];
            address2 = x[4];
            City = x[5];
            State = x[6];
            zipCode = x[7];
            phoneNum = x[8];
            Email = x[9];
            cWeb = x[10];
            cPosition = x[11];
            youCompany = x[12];
            mealPlan = x[13];
            billFirstName = x[14];
            billLastName = x[15];
            creditType = x[16];
            cNum = x[17];
            cCSV = x[18];
            cEXPMo = x[19];
            cEXPYr = x[20];
            work1 = x[21];
            work2 = x[22];
            work3 = x[23];    

            document.getElementById('title').value = title;
            document.getElementById('fname').value = firstName;
            document.getElementById('lname').value = lastName;
            document.getElementById('add1').value = address1;
            document.getElementById('add2').value = address2;
            document.getElementById('city').value = City;
            document.getElementById('state').value =State;
            document.getElementById('zip').value = zipCode;
            document.getElementById('tele').value = phoneNum;
            document.getElementById('email').value = Email;
            document.getElementById('web').value = cWeb;
            document.getElementById('position').value = cPosition;
            document.getElementById('company').value = youCompany;
            document.getElementById('meal').value = mealPlan;
            document.getElementById('bfname').value = billFirstName;
            document.getElementById('blname').value = billLastName;
            document.getElementById('cardtype').value = creditType;
            document.getElementById('cardnum').value = cNum;
            document.getElementById('csv').value = cCSV;
            document.getElementById('expmo').value = cEXPMo;
            document.getElementById('expyr').value = cEXPYr;
            document.getElementById('ws1').value = work1;
            document.getElementById('ws2').value = work2;
            document.getElementById('ws3').value = work3;
        }
    }

    function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)===' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "error";
    }
```

Comment: It's not really a good practice to keep THAT much data in a cookie.  Any number of things can happen that it would get lost.  Is there a reason you are not storing this in a more persistent place?

Comment: This is for a school project that requires saving via cookies, I had chosen to store it all in one cookie because I had read that you should not have too many cookies for you risk losing some if you reach a users max allowed cookies.

Comment: If you're allowed to use packages and not restricte to pure JS, check out (js.cookie on npm)[https://www.npmjs.com/package/js.cookie]